# Conditional aggregation of rows in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I have some data with 2 columns in the following format:

```
160 B
540 I
550 I
590 B
370 I
```

And I want to merge the cells that come in the form of `B` in addition to consecutive `I`'s (i.e. `BI*`):

```
160 540 550
590 370
```

How can I achieve something like this with polars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for the consecutive `"B" -> "I"` pairs, toggle those to `true` and `cumsum` between them.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "nums": [160, 540, 550, 590, 370],
    "letters": ["B", "I", "I", "B", "I"]
})

(df.groupby(
    [
        ((pl.col("letters") + pl.col("letters").shift(-1)) == "BI")
        .cumsum()
        .alias("cumsum")
    ],
    maintain_order=True,
).agg([pl.col("nums").list()]))
```

This outputs:

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────┬─────────────────┐
│ cumsum ┆ nums            │
│ ---    ┆ ---             │
│ u32    ┆ list [i64]      │
╞════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1      ┆ [160, 540, 550] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ [590, 370]      │
└────────┴─────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with the for loop, that's it. I tried also with polars' data manipulation functions but I didn't manage to do it this way.

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "nums": [160, 540, 550, 590, 370],
    "letters": ["B", "I", "I", "B", "I"]
})

out = []
for d, l in zip(df["nums"], df["letters"]):
    if l == "B":
        out.append([d])
    elif l == "I":
        out[-1].append(d)
    else:
        raise Exception("Unknown letter: " + l)

print(out)
```